# bibtex error using revtex

Tags: bibtex, miktex, revtex

I receive an error in MikTex, using revtex.  The error occurs when bibtex activates.

Any ideas on a solution?  Output is below:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6930 64-bit)

The top-level auxiliary file: humanomicsPropertiesPreprint.aux

The style file: apsrev4-2.bst

Database file #1: humanomicsPropertiesPreprintNotes.bib

Database file #2: bib.bib

control{REVTEX42Control}, control.key{N/A}, control.author{N/A}, control.editor{N/A}, control.title{N/A}, control.pages{N/A}, control.year{N/A}, control.eprint{N/A}, 
control{apsrev42Control}, control.key{N/A}, control.author{08}, control.editor{1}, control.title{0}, control.pages{0}, control.year{1}, control.eprint{N/A}, 

Warning--jnrlst (dependency: not reversed) set 1

apsrev4-2.bst 2019-01-14 (MD) hand-edited version of apsrev4-1.bst

Control: key (0) 

Control: author (8) initials jnrlst

Control: editor formatted (1) identically to author

Control: production of article title (0) allowed

Control: page (0) single

Control: year (1) truncated

Control: production of eprint (0) enabled

Warning--empty year in SIC
"J. High Energy Phys." is a string literal, `journal' is a missing field
---they aren't the same literal types for entry Cou
while executing---line 3516 of file apsrev4-2.bst
```

Answer (score 6):

The error is caused by file apsrev4-2.bst in the ReVTeX4-2 distribution. To fix it replace in the preamble

`\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-2}`
by
`\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}`

Naturally, the package RevTeX4-1 should be installed. Otherwise, you have to install the file apsrev4-1.bst manually.

Answer (score 6):

You can still use revtex4-2 by manually adding `, journal = ""` to each `@article` without a journal field (i.e., those have only an arxiv number).